# different result while using loop

Tags: r

I have a problem while adding a new value to a list (or vector). This is my code:

```
window<-4
n<-1

normaltimeseries<-c(1,2,3,1,2,3,3,2,1,1,2,3,3,1,2,1)

energie <- function(x) {(Re(fft(x)))^2+(Im(fft(x)))^2}


normaltimeseries<-matrix(normaltimeseries)


while(n+window <= length(normaltimeseries[,1]))
{
  ena<-sum(energie(normaltimeseries[n:(n+window-1),1]))
  append(ena,m1)
  n<-n+1
}
m1
```

and I have this result:

```
92  92  92  60  40  60  92 104  92  92  72  60
```

If I calculate it without any loop like this:

```
ena<-sum(energie(normaltimeseries[1:4,1]))
```

I have `60` as a resualt

```
ena<-sum(energie(normaltimeseries[2:5,1]))
```

I have `72`
and so on,which are totaly difference from what I hve calculated in a loop? can some one explain me, why I see a difference and how can I solve that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read `?append` carefully. The vector to "modify" is the first argument and the value to be appended is the second argument. So you meant to do `append(m1, end)` and not the other way around.

I put quotes around "modify" because the function has no side-effect, i.e. it does not really modify `m1` but returns a whole new vector. So you'll want to assign it so it does not get lost:

```
m1 <- append(m1, ena)
```

Of course, don't forget to initialize `m1` at the top of your script, before the loop:

```
m1 <- c()
```

Finally, be aware that growing an object iteratively can be memory and time consuming. It should work fine if you do not have too many iterations though.